# Button class pass through Ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have some problem. I am using Laravel. I pass html string from controller using Ajax. Example:

```
 $html .= '<span class="book-wishlist-btn addwish" id="addwish'.$book->id.'" data-placement="left" title="'.$title.'" style="'.$style.'" book_id="'.$book->id.'">';
                $html .= '<i data-feather="heart">';
                $html .= '</i>';
                $html .= '</span>';
```

At my blade, I have 2 Ajax which is to retrieve data I pass from controller and to run class addwish. Span class id (addwish) will trigger based on jquery click function.

Ajax to retrieve $html string:

```
$.ajax({
                method:"POST",  
                dataType: "json",
                url: "{{url('books')}}",
                data: {html:html},
                success: function(data){
                    feather.replace();
                }
            });
```

Ajax to trigger addwish class click:

```
 $(".addwish").click(function(){

            $.ajax({  
                url : "{{url('addwishlist')}}",
                //my codes goes here..
            });
        });
```

My problem is the addwish class not detect. Anyone can help give an idea? Thank you

Comment: You have to use Event delegation. `$(document).on("click", ".addwish", function(){`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Tq. It solve my problem now. Just add delegation. But, why `$(".addwish").click(function(){` not run correctly?

Comment: Because the new `.addwish` element is not part of the DOM. When the browser reads this line `$(".addwish").click(function(){` only those elements at that time that has the class `addwish` will get the click event.

Comment: Please try this

    $('body').on('click','.addwish',function(){
    $.ajax({
    // You may proceed with your request.
    })
    })
If this doesn't work then let me know, I am happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead of your previous click code:

```
$(".addwish").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({  
        url : "{{url('addwishlist')}}",
        //my codes goes here..
    });
});
```

reference to : [Click not working after ajax content has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584971/click-not-working-after-ajax-content-has-loaded)